# Problema al instalar Yii2 via Composer

Tags: cmd, yii2, composer

Estoy tratando de instalar mi aplicacion en Yii2 via Composer pero cuando voy a ejecutar el siguiente comando en el cmd de windows `composer self-update` me sale el siguiente error `composer no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable`

Cualquier respuesta seria de mucha de ayuda, quedo pendiente gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al estar trabajando en ambiente Windows, necesitas en las variables de entorno añadir la ruta donde esta el bin de composer, como no lo encuentra por eso te marca ese error

Pasos:

1. Click derecho en equipo
2. Propiedades
3. Configuración avanzada del sistema
4. Click en variables de entorno
5. Dentro de variables de sistema busca la opción que diga **Path**
6. Agrega la siguiente ruta

> C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin

Adapta esa ruta equivalente a tu pc, cierra el cmd vuelvelo a abrir, si no hay mayores detalles; escribe composer y dte debería regresar ya los comandos de composer y reconocer dicho comando

> Recuerda cada ruta que pongas en la variable de sistema separala por **;** es decir después del último valor que aparezca en dicha ruta coloca el ; y pega la ruta equivalente a la que puse yo mas arriba